# How to automatically fix MISSING reference in a dll when a referenced library is broken in VB6?

Tags: dll, vb6

What do you do when you break compatibility on a common library used by many other libraries on your development machine?

What I usually do is:

```
For every dll that reference the broken one
 Checkout dll
 Checkout vbp project
 Open vpb project with VB6 Ide
 Click on References button 
 Uncheck MISSING reference and OK
 Click on References button 
 Check references and OK
 Click on Make dll
 Close project
```

This can be a pita activity, when you have many Dll to recompile and it can be error prone because you could miss some Dll.
I think this problem is more related to development machine; on our staging/production server we have build tools that fix the MISSING problem automatically.

What's your best practice to handle this common scenario on your local machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Way We Work](http://users.skynet.be/wvdd2/Compiling/The_Way_we_Work/the_way_we_work.html) -- section **Handle broken references** is almost the way *we* work.

Here is a link to the tool by LJ Johnson -- [Take Control of Your Build Cycle](http://mvps.org/st-software/Code/BuildCycle.zip). We are using a custom build tools in our daily builds that reads separate REF files.

Comment: Do you launch custom build script on your developer local machine too?

Comment: No, I'm just getting latest in the morning from the nightly build. Then I usually set all vbp's to project compatibility (with a batch) because intellisense gets much faster in the IDE. I don't care if I'm breaking compatibility during the day because next build will fix "dropped" references automagically.

Comment: Ah ok but setting vbp to project compatibility presuppose that you have checked out every project.Do you develop alone?

Comment: Without checking out anything my batch is setting off read-only attrib of VBPs, find&replace `CompatibleMode="2"` -> `CompatibleMode="1"`, restore read-only. I'm currently working in a team of 4 dev.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the vbp with notepad then you should be able to update the reference without actually opening the project.  Obviously you'll need to make sure you give it the correct CLSID.

Comment: Obviously, you don't have to do this manually, you could write a script to update the vpb, and then another to recompile it after.

Comment: Yes you are right.How could the script know the CLSID of the broken dll?Do you have any example on how to recompile using a script?

Comment: VB6.exe /m project should recompile for you.

Can you not just feed the old and new CLSID values into the script?

Comment: How do you get the CLSID of a specific DLL?

Comment: You can look in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT